# Angular Schema Form - Custom Field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm trying to add new form fields to angular schema form directive. The documentation (https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/extending.md) says to use a function call like below to do that,

```
 schemaFormDecoratorsProvider.addMapping(
  'bootstrapDecorator',
  'datepicker',
  'directives/decorators/bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.html'
);
```

I'm new to angularjs and I'm not sure from where to call this function. I've tried different methods and nothing made it work. Can someone provide a jsfiddle to show how to do this, or give me some hints..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link in the example states ("Ex. from the [datepicker add-on](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form-datepicker/blob/master/src/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L18)"), you need to add a following config() block:

```
angular.module('schemaForm').config(
['schemaFormProvider', 'schemaFormDecoratorsProvider', 'sfPathProvider',
  function(schemaFormProvider,  schemaFormDecoratorsProvider, sfPathProvider) {

    // Use schemaFormProvider,  schemaFormDecoratorsProvider, sfPathProvider here
    // to configure the custom field
  }
]);
```

It can be just added on the top level of your app code, like this:

```
angular.module('schemaForm').config(...)

var app = angular.module("test", ["schemaForm"]);

app.controller("FormController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.schema = { ... }
    ...
});
```

**Update**: [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serebrov/o0yced6o/1/) demonstrating this.